# Разные результаты выдачи google поиска в разных браузерах

Tags: поиск, запрос, индексация

Уважаемые специалисты, скажите, возможно такое, что поисковая выдача google по некоторым ключевым запросам разная в разных браузерах. Например ещё вчера мой сайт был на 6 странице по определённому запросу, сейчас смотрю в **Firefox** и **Opera** он в конце первой уже странице, но в **Chrome** остался так же на 6-ой странице.

Comment: а вы в режиме инкогнито попробуйте)

Comment: в режиме инкогнито какого браузера?

Comment: всех, результаты персонализированы и зависят от многих параметров.

Comment: если посмотреть в приватном режиме по всем браузерам, то результаты одинаковые. И что это значит? Но пользователи другие как видят? не в режиме же приватном они пользуются поиском?

Comment: Другие пользователи видят персонализированную для них выдачу. Сайты, потенциально интересные именно им, оказываются в поисковой выдаче выше, соответственно, потенциально опуская или поднимая ваш. В среднем приватный режим будет показывать более-менее достоверную картинку "случайного посетителя".